# Delay/timeout a jquery .mouseover event

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay, mouseover

I have this

```
  });

  $('#zSlider .description li').mouseover(function(){

    $('#zSlider').carousel($(this).index('#zSlider .description li'));

  });
```

I want the mouseover even to be delayed by 1 second. i asked this question before and I'm sure i was given the correct answer but i couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a timeout

```
$('#zSlider .description li').mouseover(function(){
    var me = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#zSlider').carousel($(me).index('#zSlider .description li'));
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work. here is the website with the new code http://blog.vishopper.com/ its the carousel, its supposed to move every 5 seconds (it does) and if you mouse over for 1 second I want it to go to the corresponding image

Comment: What do you mean "go to the corresponding image" ?

Comment: its supposed to display the image in the carousel that corresponds to that tab

Comment: it is because when you call the timeout the `this` context changes (to the window), therefore you must store the reference to `this` and use that reference. EDIT MADE

Comment: thank you very much. I'm going to pick up some basic coding instructions tomorrow, this is my firts time doing anything with code. Spending so much time on such simple stuff.